# Problem with handling nested dictionary on Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Testing Django Rest Framework. I receive the following JSON as a result of the POST request for entry (it is important here that the keys of the dictionary, the rest are trifles):

```
    {
        "title": "Test title10",
        "description": "Test description10",
        "client": {
            "name": "Egor10",
            "surname": "Egor11",
            "phone": "1645342534532",
            "adress": "st. Egor9, 53453"
        },
        "products": ["Karamel", "Shokolad", "Limon", "Banan"],
        "delivery_adress": "st. Egor44",
        "delivery_date": "2022-23-09:44:00",
        "delivery_code": "4562gdgll"
    }
```

I have two models:

```
from django.db import models


class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)


class Order(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    delivery_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    delivery_adress = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='orders')
```

Next, I want to make a serializer and look towards **SlugRelatedField or Nested relationships** to process the nested dictionary relationship:

```
"client": {
    "name": "Egor10",
    "surname": "Egor11",
    "phone": "1645342534532",
    "adress": "st. Egor9, 53453"
}
```

For SlugRelatedField I tried this story in the serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     orders = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='phone'
     )

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'delivery_code', 'delivery_adress', 'orders']
```

In views.py I do the standard processing:

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save()
```

And this whole story does not work and most often the **KeyError: 'client' error**, which is generally logical.

Tell me what I'm doing wrong and where to drip?

Answer (score 0):

I think the field name should be `client`, not `orders`.
The name `orders`, which is the `related_name`, can be used in the `client` model and its serializer.

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     client = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='phone'
     )

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'delivery_code', 'delivery_adress', 'client']
```

Comment: The problem is not solved. The same error is thrown. TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Perhaps you can write in full what the serializer should look like for both models?